# Ruby Kernel module methods used as Object class methods

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, object-model

Say I want to patch the `Kernel` module with one method I just came up with:

```
module Kernel
  def say_hello
    puts "hello world"
  end
end
```

I can now certainly do this:

```
Object.new.say_hello # => hello world
```

but I can also do the following which I normally shouldn't be able to do:

```
Object.say_hello # => hello world
```

Since `Object` includes `Kernel` it takes its instance methods and thus all `Object` instances should respond to `say_hello`. So far so good.

However `Object.say_hello` seems to be a class method which could only be justified if we had done something similar to this:

```
class << Object
  def say_hello
    puts "hello world"
  end  
end
```

Storing `say_hello` in `Object`'s singleton class would allow us to use it as a class method but instead `Kernel` in just included in `Object` which shouldn't allow this behavior. But it does. Does anybody have a clue why?

Thanks

Comment: It's really simple: `Object` is a `Class` which is an `Object`. That's why it responds to `say_hello` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `Kernel` is just included in `Object` [...]

That is correct.

> [...] which shouldn't allow this behavior.

You overlook that classes are objects, too.

---

Let's see where the `say_hello` method comes from if `obj` is an instance of `Object`:

```
obj = Object.new

obj.method(:say_hello)
#=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#say_hello>
```

Just as expected. `obj` is an instance of `Object` and `Object` includes `Kernel`:

```
obj.class.include? Kernel
#=> true

obj.class.ancestors
#=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

---

Now let's see what happens if `obj` is the class `Object`:

```
obj = Object

obj.method(:say_hello)
#=> #<Method: Class(Kernel)#say_hello>
```

This time `obj` is an instance of `Class` and `Class` also includes `Kernel`:

```
obj.class.include? Kernel
#=> true

obj.class.ancestors
#=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

---

Ruby's [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Scope) notes that class methods are in fact just instance methods defined on the class object: (emphasis added)

> ```
> class C
>   def self.my_method
>     # ...
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> However, this is simply a special case of a greater syntactical power in Ruby, the ability to add methods to any object. Classes are objects, so **adding class methods is simply adding methods to the Class object**.